# Terraform: Custom user authentication on digitalocean

Tags: digital-ocean, terraform

With vagrant I was able to set a droplet up with a custom user:

```
config.ssh.username = 'living'
config.ssh.private_key_path = "./keys/qa.openssh"
```

Currently, I'm using `terraform`. Nevertheless I don't quite figure out how to set a custom user instead of `root`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of ways in which you could approach this:

**1: Use a Terraform provisioner to create your user:**

Terraform ships with a number of provisioners that will let you perform provisioning actions on the resources it creates for you. Probably the best one for you in this situation is the [remote-exec](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/remote-exec.html) provisioner. Essentially this just allows you to run one or more shell commands on the remote resource. Using this you could then simply apply the typical Unix commands to create your `living` user and add in the correct SSH key for them (or even delegate the call out to a true configuration tool like Ansible or Chef). It might look something like this:

```
provisioner "remote-exec" {
  inline = [
    "adduser living",
    "..."
  ]
}
```

You may also be able to use the [file](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/file.html) provisioner to copy over configuration files, or even the [chef](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/chef.html) provisioner.

The thing to remember with provisioners is that they only run once when the resource is created.

**2: Create a machine image with the correct SSH configuration in place**

An alternative is to create an image for your Droplets that has the basic SSH configuration and users already set. This way you simply ask Terraform to create resources that you know to have the correct configuration already. This is what we'd call immutable infrastructure.

You could for example use [Packer](https://www.packer.io/) (which is also from Hashicorp) to create your Droplet with the `living` user already created. Packer is basically a tool for creating machine images with numerous providers such as AWS and also [DigitalOcean](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/digitalocean.html).

Once you had created your new image for your Droplet, you would simply update your Terraform resource definitions to ensure that you launch the correct image.

Given the choice, I personally would take option 2 as I much prefer the immutable infrastructure route. However if you're just playing around with Terraform, then option 1 will work just fine.